# Exchange 2010 Corrupt database and failed initialization

Tags: exchange-2010, corruption

I have a corrupt database, I was in the process of repairing and moving the mailboxes to a new database. I got complete with all but a few mailboxes and the system crashed.

Now when attempting to open Exchange via EMC the server fails to initilize. The errors revolve around the OAB cannot load and the original mailbox failed to load. I am assuming the failure it related to the corruption and that the OAB is in the corrupt mailbox.

I had that mailbox dismounted, but it was set to automatically set to remount at startup. I cannot load the EMC or Shell, so how can I recover from this without reinstalling Exchange?

Comment: Are you running this on a RAID array? What kind? Do you have a bad hard drive? This behavior strikes me of a bad hard drive with no redundancy.

Comment: No it is on a RAID array, not sure on RAID level, as it is managed hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop what you're doing and call Microsoft for support.

DANGER, Will Robinson!  DANGER!

This is not something you want to muck about with, and E2k10 is new enough that they will probably want to know about these edge cases.  They may even void your call cost (if you don't have a support contract.)

Comment: Why the downvote? (Especially over a year after the OP said it was the right thing, and at the time, E2k10 was new?)

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider taking a look at the following article:

http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/eseutil-part2.html

Comment: +1, but when this kind of thing happens (especially on such a fresh edition), I'd rather have a Microsoft Engineer on tap in case things go pear-shaped.  (Well, more than they have already...)

Comment: Absolutely, when that is available and practical. Unless it is a specific product issue, there is a good chance that they will go through a similar route with the product utilities at hand. Hopefully there are backups in place, if not, time to at least try and get a state preserving copy to head off any further possible digressions/data loss while troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, ran though those before ending up here and with MS support. In the end MS support did the same things and the file was just corrupted with no hope. Thankfully there are some third party software that can still read the EDB file, so I was able to recover the data. Created new DB and all is back to normal. I have to say MS support was great 20 hours of troubleshooting for $260. Can't beat it!